# Detect plugin/theme installation (via upload)

Tags: plugins, themes, uploads

I am currently trying to detect when an administrator uploads (and installs) a theme or plugin.

The code I wrote is very fragile because it depends on the chance that the plugin/theme's name is the same as the uploaded zip file (which is rarely the case).

```
function EventFileUploaded($attachmentID){
    if(isset($_REQUEST['action'])){
        $file = get_attached_file($attachmentID);
        switch($_REQUEST['action']){
            case 'upload-theme':
                HandleThemeUpload($file);
                break;
            case 'upload-plugin':
                HandlePluginUpload($file);
                break;
        }
    }
}
add_action('delete_attachment', 'EventFileUploaded');

function HandleThemeUpload($fileName){
    $themes = wp_get_themes();
    // TODO somehow find which theme in $themes was installed from $fileName
}

function HandlePluginUpload($fileName){
    $plugins = get_plugins();
    // TODO somehow find which plugin in $plugins was installed from $fileName
}
```

I basically need to fill up the two TODOs marked above. This is a sample of the code I was using:

```
$fileName = explode('.', basename($fileName));
foreach(get_plugins() as $pluginFile => $plugin){
    if(strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $plugin['Name'])) == $fileName){
        $newPlugin = $plugin;
        break;
    }
}
// use $newPlugin if set
```

Of course the code above fails in some situations.

*PS: I wasn't sure what tags to use, feel free to suggest better ones.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet here is to hook into the flow at the time of uploading and processing the uploaded file.

There is a filter (line 327, file.php):

```
apply_filters( 'wp_handle_upload', array( 'file' => $new_file, 'url' => $url, 'type' => $type ), 'upload' );
```

You could create a filter within which you do nothing else but create a global variables to hold the current values for:

```
wp_get_themes();
wp_get_plugins();
```

then, within your existing functions

```
HandleThemeUpload() { }
HandlePluginUpload() { }
```

you get the themes and plugins **again** and then compare these results with your previous global results using array_diff(): e.g.

```
$NewPlugin = array_diff( $LatestPlugins, $OldGlobalPlugins );
```

Then you have the new plugins / themes.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hmm, I was thinking about doing something on those lines. Didn't know the exact hooks to use though. Thanks!

Comment: No worries... you'll really want to have the WordPress source code handy to dig through.  It's a maze, but you'll eventually get the hang of it :)